# Rights to "Gotham" and Batman after Fox's proposed sale?

Tags: copyright, disney, gotham, 20th-century-fox

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotham_(TV_series))

> Gotham is an American crime drama television series developed by Bruno Heller, based on characters published by **DC Comics and appearing in the Batman franchise**, primarily those of James Gordon and Bruce Wayne. The series stars Ben McKenzie as the young Gordon, while Heller executive produces, along with Danny Cannon, who also directed the pilot.

The Original network of "Gotham" is Fox and

> Gotham premiered on Fox on September 22, 2014. In May 2017, Fox renewed the series for a fourth season, which premiered on September 21, 2017.

Does this mean now that [Disney has bought Fox](https://www.forbes.com/sites/howardhomonoff/2017/12/15/disney-buys-fox-its-not-a-small-world-after-all/#6750092b79ac) Marvel own the rights to certain DC characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**

According to [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/merrillbarr/2017/12/11/disney-fox-merger-gotham-lucifer-lethal-weapon-brooklyn-nine-nine-99-brooklyn99/#133789c54c8d):

> Part of Disney’s acquisition is set to include the purchase of 20th Century Fox Television. This is not the same thing as Disney purchasing the Fox network, which is not part of the deal.
>
> What Disney is potentially buying is every show Fox produces, including The Simpsons, Family Guy, The Gifted, Empire and off-network shows like This is Us and Modern Family. However, the Hollywood giant will have no power over shows provided by third-party studios airing on Fox, including the Warner Bros. owned Gotham, Lucifer and Lethal Weapon, and Universal owned Brooklyn Nine-Nine.

Disney only owns what Fox **produces**.

Here is the [updated infographic](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/12/14/marvel-characters-ownership-rights-infographic/) of what Disney owns:

[image]

Comment: Wow I thought Marvel had the rights to Venom?? .... and Stan Lee?? LOL

Comment: Shouldn't Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch be in one of those bubbles?  I thought they were both dual-owned?  Also, funny but sad to see Stan outside the circle.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch were part of Fox, so now there are part of Disney.

Comment: They also have a disclaimer at the bottom, where it says it is impossible to show every character in the Marvel Universe in the infographic.